# How to switch to a new window using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

In my code i have reached to a page using selenium in whihc there is a link which opens as a popup on the same page, but that link is using , so it is like a new page which is opening in new window.

I am able to click to that link and open the page to, but when i am doing driver.getWindowHandles(), it is returning the size as 1 only and not 2, because of which i am not able to switch to new window.

Below is the code that i am using:

```
    String parent = driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='abc']")).click();
    // after clicking on the link
    try{
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    Set<String> availableWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();//this set size is
   // returned as 1 and not 2
    String newWindow = null;
    for (String window : availableWindows) {
        if (!parent.equals(window)) {
            newWindow = window;
        }
    }
    assertNotNull(newWindow);

    // switch to new window
    driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
    // do assert the elements in the new window
    // and then close the new window
    driver.close();
    // switch to parent
    driver.switchTo().window(parent);
    // close main window
    driver.close();}
    catch(Exception e){
```

Since the popup window is the part of the master window itself, ie, why i am not able to get the correct size by doing getWindowHandle();

but my requirement is to save the popup page only.
Right now the save code is saving the master page details along with the popup content since every time the masterpage driver is called.

Is there any workaround that i can do to get the driver of the popup page only?

Save code is generic and that is not important in this reference.
All i want is to get the driver of the popup page only

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the link you need to wait until Selenium realizes there are now totally 2 windows.

```
String parent = driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='alertHistoryLink']")).click();
    // after clicking on the link
    // call the method numberOfWindowsToBe as follows
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);
    wait.until(numberOfWindowsToBe(2));

public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> numberOfWindowsToBe(final int numberOfWindows) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                driver.getWindowHandles();
        return driver.getWindowHandles().size() == numberOfWindows;
      }
    };
}
```

> All i want is to get the driver of the popup page only

**EDIT:** The driver for the master window is the driver for the popup as popup itself is the part of the master window. The only exception is, if the popup is present in a frame, then you need to switch to the frame then you can perform actions on the elements present in the popup.

EDIT: If I understand you correctly, you want to get the page source of the popup. As popup is part of the master window. What I would do is

popup.getAttribute("innerHTML");
Where popup is of type WebElement.

For example if HTML of the master window is like

```
 <html>
<head>
.....
</head>
<body>
...
...
..
<div id = popup> 
//html elements present in popup
</div>
...
..
</head>
</html>
```

then

`WebElement popup = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='popup']"));`

```
String htmlInsidePopup = popup.getAttribute("innerHTML");
System.out.println(htmlInsidePopup);
```

will solve the problem.

Comment: not working. it terminates before going inside the numberofwindowstobe method

Comment: it is still returning the size as 1

Comment: @user2478636 that could only mean that the popup is not a window. It belongs to the same page. Don't do any switching and perform whatever action you want to on the popup.

Comment: Add html of popup to the question and the actions you want to do on popup.