# New window handles disappearing in IE, can't switch to new window

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium

I am using the latest version of Selenium (2.37.0) with C# in Internet Explorer 10 (using the latest 32-bit InternetExplorerDriver, 2.37.0) to log in to a webpage, click on a button that opens a new window, and then changes focus to the new window.

Originally I was using this code in Firefox, and it would work every time:

```
// Get handle for original window
string parentHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

// Click on button for new window
driver.FindElement(By.Id("buttonForNewWindow")).Click();

// Get list of all window handles
ReadOnlyCollection<string> allWindowHandles = driver.WindowHandles;

// Loop over all handles and switch to new child window
foreach (string handle in allWindowHandles)
{
    if (handle != parentHandle)
    {
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

I have pinpointed the problem. Before I open the new window, I use `driver.WindowHandles.Count` to get the number of window handles, and (as expected) it tells me that there is only one window handle. Then, when I click the button for the new window, it tells me (again, as expected) that there are two window handles. But before the code gets to the line for `driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);`, the number of window handles has dropped back down to one, **even though both windows are still visible**.

So somehow one of the window handles is getting lost. I have confirmed (using a bunch of `Console.WriteLine` statements) that the window handle that is dropped is the new one. I also used the `Stopwatch` class to time how long it takes for the new window handle to be dropped:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

// Wait until the number of windows has changed from 1 to 2
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until((_driver) => { return _driver.WindowHandles.Count != windowsBefore; });

// Start stopwatch
sw.Start();

int numberOfWindows = driver.WindowHandles.Count;

while (numberOfWindows == 2)
{
    numberOfWindows = driver.WindowHandles.Count;
}

sw.Stop();

Console.Write("\nTime elapsed: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
```

After running this a few times, I found that the number of window handles typically drops back to one **in less than 50 milliseconds**. However, one time the window handle lasted much longer; here are the original numbers:

```
Time elapsed: 47 ms
Time elapsed: 31 ms
Time elapsed: 47 ms
Time elapsed: 2861 ms
Time elapsed: 30 ms
```

I have also confirmed that **this problem does not occur in Firefox**. When I run the same code in Firefox, I find that the number of window handles changes from 1 to 2, *and stays that way*, as it should.

It seems that **others are having this problem** as well. [This person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767109/how-to-switch-to-a-new-window-using-selenium) finds that when they open a new window and wait 1000 milliseconds, getWindowHandles() returns a value of 1 instead of 2. And [this person](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-users/J7bV14i6kkE/eWsqV5UzkCUJ) on the Selenium Google Group seems to be having the same issue.

**My question:** Given that the handle for a newly-opened window remains open for (typically) less than 50 milliseconds, what is the most efficient possible way to switch to a new window in Internet Explorer 10 with Selenium? Or is there something I should be doing differently to prevent new window handles from getting lost?

Comment: What version of Selenium have you been using?

Comment: @Richard The version of Selenium is 2.35.0. The version of IEDriverServer is 2.35.3.0.

Comment: Have you tried manually logging in with IE 10 to see if the same behavior occurs?

Comment: @Richard The new window opens up fine and is in focus (at least, visually). The problem is in the IWebDriver: Selenium is unable to switch the driver to the new window.

Comment: Ah, I thought maybe the window itself was closing in IE 10.  I tried a similar test with IE 10, Selenium 2.37, the 32 bit IE driver, and I was able to switch windows.  I'd recommend getting the 32 bit 2.35.3.0 IE  driver if you were using the 64 bit, or updating to 2.37.  I'd also suggest trying your test against IE 9 if you haven't already to see if you get the same behavior.

Comment: Just remembered this:  Selenium does not like a second window if you have ANY IE browsers opened other than the one Selenium opens itself.  So, I'd recommend closing all IE browsers, then run the test again.

Comment: @Richard I only have one window of IE open when running these tests, so that shouldn't be a problem -- but that's good to know. I always try to keep conditions as ideal as possible when running Selenium so that it doesn't complain. I've re-run my program, and sometimes it fails to switch windows. But many times it actually succeeds at window-switching, but then it fails on a "wait" for an element to be present (e.g., `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Name("MENU")));`). In all failed cases, the number of handles drops from 2 to 1 at some point. Now I will try updating Selenium.

Comment: @Richard I've updated to the latest version of Selenium for C# (2.37.0) and the 32-bit Internet Explorer Driver (2.37.0.0), and I am still having the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to give an update, in case anyone else has this same problem and finds this page. I haven't found a solution to my problem, but I came up with a workaround.

Originally, I was clicking on a link that opened a new window, and I was having trouble navigating Selenium to the new window. What I did instead was dig through the page's source code, find the button that I was clicking on, and figure out where that button points to. It would have been easiest if it was a simple hyperlink (www.whatever.com/....), but instead it was a Javascript function. That Javascript function builds up the hyperlink using some fixed characters and some variables; for example:

```
link(username, date) = "http://www.google.com/user=" + username + "?date=" + date;
```

So, going along with this example, I just figured out what variables were being fed in (username, date, etc.), built the URL myself, and navigated to it directly. Thus I didn't even have to open up and navigate to a new window at all.

Comment: I just want to point out here that you've not included the source code for a set of HTML pages that would reproduce the issue. Working with popup windows in the IE driver is not globally broken for all users of all websites everywhere. Without a set of HTML pages that reproduces the issue, it will be nearly impossible to provide any sort of a resolution. Please note that this set of pages does not need to be the exact application where you see the issue, simply one that works similarly enough to reproduce it.

Comment: @JimEvans Point taken. I just created a sample page that reproduces this issue. I thought it might be better to put it up in a new question; [here's a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777318/c-selenium-new-window-handles-disappearing-in-ie).

Comment: HI @DanielCharles, is this issue solved? I am using Selenium with IE 11. When I click on a button, the original window gets closed and another window is opened using window.open in javascript. The code is losing window handles. I have disabled Enable protected mode for all zones in IE. driver.windowhandles.count returns 0 always. Any help will be a real life safer.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to incorrect security settings in Internet Explorer. You need to clear the check box for Enable Protected Mode for each of the four zones in the Internet Options dialog Security tab. The four zones must match.

[image]

Manual Method:

1. Open Internet Explorer.
2. Click the Tools icon or press Alt-X.
3. Click Internet options menu item or Alt-o.
4. Click the Security tab.
5. Click the Internet icon.
6. Clear the Enable Protected Mode checkbox.
7. Click the Local intranet icon.
8. Clear the Enable Protected Mode checkbox.
9. Repeat for the Trusted sites and the Restricted sites.
10. Click Apply button.
11. Acknowledge the security risk pop up, accepting the risk.
12. Close Internet Explorer.

Now your InternetExplorerDriver should show the correct number of window handles and be able to switch between windows.

In my case manual changes only lasted until I rebooted and then the settings reverted, so I recommend modifying the registry each test run to be sure.

C# Example Using Registry:

```
            const string zonesPath =
                @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\";
            const string internetZonePath = zonesPath + "3";
            const string restrictedZonePath = zonesPath + "4";
            const string name = "2500";
            const int value = 3;
            Registry.SetValue(internetZonePath, name, value, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            Registry.SetValue(restrictedZonePath, name, value, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

The zones are:

- Local computer: 0
- Intranet: 1
- Trusted sites: 2
- Internet: 3
- Restricted sites: 4

The path to each zone is: "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\{zone number above}.

The name of the key is always "2500".

The value to turn off protected mode is "3".

To turn on protected mode set the value to "0".

In order to get all of the handles, all the zones must be set to the same value.