# driver.WindowHandles just pass count one windowhandle when there're two instances of Internet Explorer are open

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, window-handles

Using Selenium WebDriver, I am trying to do UI Automation, where I face this **scenario:** 
 From **InternetExplorer1**, in my webapp as I click a menu in a tab, new **InternetExplorer2** Instance loads the Url. So I get two IEs. Now I need to switch to IE2 and click the logout button over there.
for this I have the code :

```
[Test]
public void mytest()
{
  Assert.IsTrue(IsOpen());
}

public bool IsOpen()
{
  GoToUrl();// I pass the URL over here and the element is clicked here
  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
  SwitchWindow();

  return true;
}

//Here I switch the window.
private void SwitchWindow()
{
  IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
  var currentWindow = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
  string currentWindowTitle = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return document.title");
  var availableWindows = new List<string>(driver.WindowHandles);

    foreach (string w in availableWindows)
    {
        if (w != currentWindow)
        {
            //This should switch the window.
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(w);
            //..........................
            //.........More of my automation runs here..........
            //...........................

        }
    }
}
```

But the List availablewindows just passes one item in WindowHandles.
Shouldn't it count two when I have two instances open?

Comment: Might be useful to see the code where you load a browser and click on the link. Assuming the driver instance is the same, I can't see anything wrong with this code. However, it's worth reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575095/new-window-handles-disappearing-in-ie-cant-switch-to-new-window) SO question as they seem to be encountering your issue (assuming it is IE only)

Answer (score 0):

If  InternetExplorer2 launches as a new instance of IE rather than a new tab in the same IE instance, I don't think your InternetExplorerDriver can see it.

You can try changing your IE settings so that everything launches in a new tab rather than or a new instance, or write some code to grab the url from the new IE instance and relaunch it using a new InternetExplorerDriver (I've managed to do this successfully with C# and it worked OK, but it may depend on how your web app works).