# C# IE11 selenium webdriver, No new window handles with new tab

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, tabs

Selenium Webdriver for Internet Explorer 11 is not creating a new window handle when my app opens a new tab.

The problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777318/new-window-handles-disappearing-in-ie/19794327#19794327) , which was a problem with the window handles disappearing in a fraction of a second, but in my case a new window handle isn't even created in the first place.

I used the test code from that link to check for disappearing window handles, but it never created another window handle when a new tab was opened, so the test only displayed the first console output and never the second part.

I tried using:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

but the Selenium Webdriver focus stays on the first tab, because I believe it isn't creating a new handle for the new tab.

Also, tried this:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[1]);
```

and that results in an "out of range" exception and "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

If I change the [1] to a [0], then obviously I do not get the exception because the focus is just set to the first tab.

Based on my testing with the test code in the link I provided and my own attempts, I believe that new window handles are not being created.

I tried resetting IE11 and then only changing the settings as described on Selenium's website including adding the registry key, which I used Helium's solution to that found [here](http://heliumhq.com/docs/internet_explorer).

Also, I read some suggestions of adding the websites that I am opening to the Trusted sites list in IE, but still no go.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Having the same problem in a year after. WindowHandles contains only 1 value no matter how much tabs you have opened. But it will contain more values if you will open new windows.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help someone going forward...

I have been researching this after having the same issue and whatever I tried it did not resolve it!
In the  **regedit** I added the 'BF_Cache' -> 'iexplorer.exe', added '2500' set as '3' in the zones 0,2,3,4 (was already present in zone 1) & Set the 'protected mode' to enabled but no luck... My new window would open correctly through Selenium but when debugging I confirmed only one handle was available!

> But... After I nearly gave up - I decided to **run visual studio as an
>   admin**. And as if by *Magic* Selenium picked up that there was more
>   than one window handle!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround I managed to use.

You can use javascript to open a new window. It will give you the handle.

```
string javaScript = "window.open('" + url + "','_blank', 'resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, titlebar=yes, width=1280, height=680, top=10, left=10');";

jsExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)ieDriver;
jsExecutor.ExecuteScript(javaScript);
```